# upper scope has term ‘NA’ not included in model

Tags: r

I am working on a data set and would like to do step wise logistic regression using some variables and to do so I am using the add1() function in R. A sample of the data set can be downloaded from the link here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0N-Nc7kEi4bVjhDd1FDaEE5cEE/view?usp=sharing

I thereby fit a logistic regression using:

```
train <- read.csv('training.csv')
glm.model_step_1 <- glm(loan_status ~ acc_open_past_24mths + annual_inc + avg_cur_bal + bc_open_to_buy + delinq_2yrs + dti + inq_last_6mths + installment + int_rate + mo_sin_old_il_acct + mo_sin_old_rev_tl_op + mo_sin_rcnt_rev_tl_op + mo_sin_rcnt_tl + mort_acc + mths_since_last_delinq + mths_since_recent_bc + mths_since_recent_inq + num_accts_ever_120_pd + num_actv_bc_tl + num_actv_rev_tl + num_bc_tl + num_il_tl + num_op_rev_tl + num_tl_op_past_12m + pct_tl_nvr_dlq + percent_bc_gt_75 + pub_rec_bankruptcies + revol_bal + revol_util + term + total_acc + total_bc_limit + total_il_high_credit_limit + fico_mean + addr_state + emp_length + verification_status + Count_NA + Info_missing + Engineer + Teacher + Doctor + Professor + Manager + Director + Analyst + senior + lead + consultant + home_ownership_own + home_ownership_rent + purpose_debt_consolidation + purpose_medical + purpose_credit_card + purpose_other,
                    data = train, 
                    family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

And use the `add1()` function to do a forward selection.

```
add1(glm.model_step_1, scope = train)
```

This code does not work. I get the below error:

`Error in factor.scope(attr(terms1, "factors"), list(add = attr(terms2,  : 
  upper scope has term ‘NA’ not included in model`

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

A question asked previously on datascience.stackexchange (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/checking-regression-coefficients-stability) mentioned checking for NAs. There aren't any NAs in the data set and that can be confirmed by running `sapply(train, function(x) sum(is.na(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `train` dataset of @Jash Sash has some anomalous values inside which force  `read.csv` to read some numerical variables as factors with many categories.
Anyway, I consider here a model with only few variables in order to show how to avoid the error message reported above.
Remember that the `scope` argument must be a "***formula*** giving the terms to be considered for adding or dropping"; it cannot be a data.frame like in the code of @Jash Sash.

```
train <- read.csv('training.csv')
numeric <- apply(train,2,is.factor)

glm.model_step_1 <- glm(loan_status ~ acc_open_past_24mths + avg_cur_bal + bc_open_to_buy,
                    data = na.omit(train), 
                    family = binomial(link = 'logit'))

add1(glm.model_step_1, scope=~.+delinq_2yrs+inq_last_6mths+int_rate)
```

The results is:

```
Model:
loan_status ~ acc_open_past_24mths + avg_cur_bal + bc_open_to_buy
               Df Deviance    AIC
<none>              1038.6 1046.6
delinq_2yrs     1   1037.9 1047.9
inq_last_6mths  1   1038.0 1048.0
int_rate        1   1038.0 1048.0
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Also the scope argument for `add1()` can also take a dataframe. To illustrate, please run the following code:

    `data("mtcars") ;
    lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars) ;
    add1(lm1, scope = mtcars)`

But somehow I cannot pass the data frame as an argument in my case.